# IE 8-9 JavaScript issue with long loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I got the following insistent JS issue just for IE 8-9, in other browsers my code working very well.

Case:
I have the following code in JS, which should start some server process and update progress bar with status on server side, what Jquery UI provide:

```
 $("#btnSendUser").click(function (event) {                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/StartLongProcess",
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: { userIds: users },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log("Process start");
                    }
                });
                var processId = 0;
                getStatus(processId);
            });

        function getStatus(processId) {
            var url = '/GetStatus';
            $.get(url, { clientProcessId: processId }, function (data) {
                if (!data.IsDone) {
                    $("#progress").progressbar({ value: data.Progress });                                        
                    window.setTimeout("getStatus(" + processId + ")", 350);
                }
                else {
                    $("#progress").progressbar({ value: 100 });      
                    console.log("Done");                                                            
                };
            });                                  
        }
```

In *StartLongProcess* method in current controller I starting long server process in this way:
..

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
        public void StartLongProcess(Guid[] userIds)
        {       
            ...
            var processTask = new LongProcess(MesssageService.Email.SendMails);
            processTask.BeginInvoke(service.LongProcess(userIds), new AsyncCallback(EndSendingProcess), processTask);
        }
```

Method that read current status is next:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current progress.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
        public JsonResult GetCurrentProgress(int clientProcessId)
        {
            ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            var currentProgress = MesssageService.Email.GetCurrentLog(clientProcessId);            
            return Json(currentProgress ?? new LogMessage(0), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I tested this code in Chrome and FF, in those browsers progress bar and process finished correctly always. But in IE 8-9 it looks like getStatus function can't be called in this way. Is it true? What is the best way to implement my task for all browsers?
Thanks.

Comment: How does the JavaScript code ever get the process ID value?  It looks like it's always zero from that code above.

Comment: you are calling a url every 1/350 seconds. Dit you check the network to see if that works?

Comment: @Pointy that is Sample code I guess, written/modified server side. So it differs per user/session.

Comment: @CasparKleijne ... or else the process ID is supposed to be the return value from "start long process" action, which would certainly make a lot of sense. However, the way the JavaScript is written, no attempt is made to capture that value.

Comment: Yes this code is cut a little bit,  processId variable I thinks is not a reason of IE issue. I checked code for JS error - code not contain any JS errors.

Comment: IE doesn't like `console.log` unless you have opened the Developer Tools using F12. Those statements may be what's causing your code to fail in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Anthony Grist I have checked it reason not in console.log

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne yes I checked it work well.

Comment: @Anthony Grist do you have any other ideas ? thank

Comment: @cleric Can always try `window.setTimeout(function() {getStatus(processId)},350);` rather than `window.setTimeout("getStatus(" + processId + ")", 350);`.

Comment: @Anthony Grist thank it is solve this issue. But I got new one, looks like $.get is cashing request for IE, look like I need redo $get to $ajax, but it is very strange, I call ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"); in my controller, I expect that this method should mark request like no-cache

Comment: If you want to make sure all AJAX requests aren't cached, you can use $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); at the start of your javascript file. That will apply to `.ajax()`, `.get()`, `.post()` and `.load()` calls.

Comment: @Anthony Grist Thanks you for information, you impressed me. Could you please write you answer to main trad I will mark it like answer. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at maybe just adding [ChromeFrame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) to your sight? It's quickly becoming the best solution to getting the few IE users that still exist to use the same standards as everyone else in terms of viewing a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cleric Can always try

```
window.setTimeout(function() {getStatus(processId)},350);
```

rather than

```
window.setTimeout("getStatus(" + processId + ")", 350);
```

. – Anthony Grist Jan 18 at 22:50

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't provide 'console.log()' as enviroment function.